# What does 快便は快適な場所から生まれる mean?

Tags: meaning

I found the following sentence on the wall.

> 快便は快適な場所から生まれる。

What does it mean?

My attempt is as follows

> Pleasantly defecation comes from comfortable place.

But I don't really understand what it means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your translation is great,

> Pleasant defecation comes from comfortable place.

It's speaking of going to the bathroom in a place where you're comfortable, I'm pretty sure that's it.  Depending on the context, it's either a joke or could be some kind of advice from a health pamphlet or something like that.

Comment: I agree with your answer. If I see this sentence in any public toilet, I would guess it's to encourage other users to keep it clean so that other users would not get prevented from 快便. :-)

Answer (score 2):

快便は快適な場所から生まれる。
A good defecation starts with a comfortable place.

Maybe it means that a good defecation requires a comfortable, clean toilet.

Answer (score -2):

<sub>--- Great BM comes from Great RooM ---</sub>  
 <sub>--- Clean RooM produces Clean BM ---</sub>

Maybe it was written by a restaurant (?) (or any such establishment) owner/manager, telling his employees to keep the restroom clean.

Maybe it's modelled after  [ Clear Your Desk, Clear Your Mind ] ==  ( A clear desk will help you clear your mind. ) 【 いい仕事は、快適な机から生まれる 】

【明窓浄机】 (めいそうじょうき) 明るい窓と、清らかな机。転じて、明るく清らかな書斎。

30 years ago, i used to hear this slogan  [ 快食、快便 ] alot --  usually from older folks.  Maybe our favorite old-timer has some comments to share.